# swift, Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a swift code

```
if(pendingComboOperation == nil){
    if(accumulator != nil){
        let descPart2 = symbol + String(accumulator!)
    }
    else {
        let descPart2 = ""
    }

}
else {
    let descPart2 = symbol + addBrackets(to: pendingComboOperation!.descPart2)
}

pendingComboOperation = PendingComboOperation(descPart1: description!, descPart2: descPart2)
```

and have a error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'descPart2'

Why? And how may I fix it?

Comment: If you declare the variable inside a block, it won't be available outside. For you, that means: declare `descPart2` before the if-statement and then use it inside.

Comment: @Creat0r You can accept my answer(click the checkmark) if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variables in `if` or `else` statements. The solution would be to give `descPart2` a default value:

```
var descPart2: String

if(pendingComboOperation == nil){
    if(accumulator != nil){
        descPart2 = symbol + String(accumulator!)
    } else {
        descPart2 = ""
    }

} else {
    descPart2 = symbol + addBrackets(to: pendingComboOperation!.descPart2)
}

pendingComboOperation = PendingComboOperation(descPart1: description!, descPart2: descPart2)
```

Comment: It suffices to declare the variable without initial value `let descPart2: String` if all code paths assign a value before it is used.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the feedback. I'll update my post.

Comment: Don't compare with `nil`, only to force unwrap